# Access to MIFARE card manager applet

Tags: java, android, applet, nfc, mifare

I have a working Android set-up where i can emulate a Mifare 4K tag using nfc_extra. But is there any documentation or possibility to manage the virtual card (access the Mifare Manager Applet). I read something like that on http://nelenkov.blogspot.nl (great blog), but he did not continue on the mifare part.

Much thanks!

Comment: You can get documentation from NXP if you sign up and promise not to speak about it :) http://mifare4mobile.org/downloads/specifications/ But you won't get the needed keys for commercial devices (Nexus Series, etc.), so there is not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out :). I will look into it. Keep up the good work!